# The method getWorkbook(FileInputStream) is undefined for the type Workbook

Tags: java, excel, selenium, apache-poi

I'm trying to write a Selenium code with JAVA for fetching input from excel using Apache POI. Below is the code, I'm getting the error message 'The method getWorkbook(FileInputStream) is undefined for the type Workbook' for the statement Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fs); Please help me to sort this out.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
          File file = new File("C:/Users/425413/NewWorkspace/Telecom/datafile.properties");
          
            FileInputStream fileInput = null;
            try {
                fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            
            //load properties file
            try {
                prop.load(fileInput);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\425413\\Documents\\Raji\\chromedriver_win32-for79\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(prop.getProperty("URL"));
        
        String FilePath = "d://filepath.xls";
        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(FilePath);
        Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fs);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
 WorkbookFactory.create
```